# Is there an offline program I could download for the Chinese telegraph code 中文电码?

Tags: simplified-characters

Is there an offline program I could download for the Chinese telegraph code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software recommendation

Answer (score 1):

If you have an idevice, you could always use https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chinese-telegraph-code/id658197225?mt=8

On a fairly updated Windows OS, you could use http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/chinese-telegraph-code/2ff68977-4c6a-47a3-bc2d-e0fe78c4d068